# Ionicframework , cordova and ios simulator form input issue

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, input, ionic-framework

I attach a video cause its hard for me to explain the problem i'm getting:

https://vid.me/5Mo

Actually i styled by my own the form inputs and they works like a charm but when i test the fomr on ios simulator i do this:

1. focus the input
2. touch scroll the page

then the form input is rsetted to the default background as you can see in the video it gets a white background, while i specified in css that such inputs has to be without background at all.

I tryed in many ways using the css like:

```
 .input-huge:focus, .input-huge:focus:hover{
  background:none;
}
```

but it still wont work.

Any idea?

this is the html:

```
 <ion-view data-title="Submit Shop" ng-controller="Submit">
<ion-content>
<div class="separator50"></div>
<div>
    <input class="row input-huge text-center light" ng-model="newShop.name" type="text" placeholder="Shop Name">
</div>
<div class="separator50"></div>
<div>
    <input class="row input-huge text-center light" ng-model="newShop.city" type="text" placeholder="City">
</div>
<div class="separator50"></div>
<div>
    <input class="row input-huge text-center light" ng-model="newShop.address" type="text" placeholder="Address">
</div>

<div class="separator10"></div>
<div class="separator30"></div>

<div class="row">
    <button ng-click="submit()" class="button button-light button-block font-family-1" ng-class="{'disabled':newShop.processing}">
        <span ng-show="!newShop.processing" class="positive"> Submit</span>
        <span ng-show="newShop.processing"><i class="icon ion-refreshing"></i></span>
    </button>
</div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and this is my styled inputs in css :

```
input.input-huge{
  background: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom:40px;
  color:#fff;
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
}
```

thanks in advice

Comment: Try `background:transparent;`.  I'm not sure if `background:none;` is valid.

Comment: Your example is hard to debug. Could you create a fiddle with all added style dependencies?

Comment: @mlnmln style is the default ionicframework style i didnt changed anything , just added that rule i posted above and it wont work as you can see

Answer (score 1):

Give `background-color: transparent;` or `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.0);` a try. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you can't overwrite the default background property (white) without resetting `-webkit-appearance`. Try this

```
input.input-huge {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom:40px;
    color:#fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
input.input-huge:focus {
    background: none;
}
```

Update: I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mlnmln/xogdr0d7/1/). Testing in iOS Simulator shows working results.

Update 2: Tried using more qualified selectors.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-SW24)

Comment: i tryed but it doesnt work, probably because the input is resetted when focus+scroll and not only on focus !?

Comment: Some style dependencies might be missing in my fiddle. I can't recreate your exact build without having all information.

Comment: still not getting what you need, just create a new ionicframework app and build ios platform, add that css rule i pasted on the question you are in my sistuation, tell me if it works for you or you are getting the same u see in the video

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you could create a _public_ example (something that can be inspected using Safari Dev Tools) that reproduces your exact problem. Not just a video and a bunch of code snippets. Or is that not possible for you due to some restrictions?

Comment: I have restrictions, also the bug happening only on ios simulator not on safari, and its impossible to me to make public the simulator :P

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really help you then – too much guesswork. But you know that you can remote debug UIWebView and iOS Safari running in the iOS Simulator using the Dev Tools of your locally installed Safari, right? Good luck!

Comment: but how can i simulate tap,drags over forms in safari? :P